# How to improve tag maintenance?

Tags: discussion, tags

I agree with the thinking in "[twig tag should be independent tag](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3536/twig-tag-should-be-independent-tag)", and the accepted answer to it. However this is just 1 out of *many* of such tag-issues, which I've seen happening over and over the recent past. Some (?) examples:

- What happened to all those questions that used to be tagged with [modules](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/modules) (which is gone)? If you now have a question like "Assume I have some module (doesn't matter what the module is used for), with a .info file that looks like so and so, how come it doesn't show up within the admin UI to enable my module there?".
- What about the various synonyms of [i18n-l10n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i18n-l10n)? I'm sure there used to be [i18n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i18n), and also something like [l10n-x](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/l10n-x) (don't remember what X was). But please don't tell me that i18n is the same as l10n. Moreover, [language](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/language) and/or [translation](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/translation) are, IMO, not similar examples of what you can read in (eg) [synonyms of i18n-l10n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/i18n-l10n/synonyms), which includes this:

  > If you know of **common, alternate spellings or phrasings** for this tag, add them here so we can automatically correct them in the future. For example, suggest “bike” as a synonym for bicycle, or “sock” for socks.

  With the current synonyms of [i18n-l10n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/i18n-l10n), the previous phrase should look like this also:

  > For example, suggest “bike” as a synonym for sock, or “bicycle” for socks.
- More of the same: what about the various synonyms of [users](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/users)? True, [user](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/user) is a valid one (that's like the sock and socks). But what about any of these (which sound to me like the “bicycle” and "socks" ...):

  - [profiles](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profiles) (and it's [profile](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/profile) alternative)
  - [login](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/login)
  - [registration](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/registration) (and it's [register](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/register) alternative)
- And then there are all those tags that simply got removed from all questions using them (sometimes there were hundreds of such questions). For those there is even no trace left via something that is currently considered a synonym. I wonder if there is any type of trace, or explanation about why all those tags "had to go".

**Questions**:

- How can the Drupal.SE community get more involved in deciding about these kinds of tag maintenance activities *before these activities are performed*?
- Are there any alternatives available for those users who like building lists of questions about specific topics, and for which only using "a" specific tag produces way too long lists of questions?

Answer (score -1):

What is really missing is some type of review process, which is what you can read further down on that same [synonyms of i18n-l10n](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/tags/i18n-l10n/synonyms) page, i.e.:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4, and automatically deleted when they reach a score of -2.

To my knowledge, I have not ever seen such synonym suggestion in [any of the 6 existing review queues](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review). I actually even wonder where I should go look to see if any reviews are outstanding. To me such synonym suggestions should be either variations of "tag edit suggestions" in the [Suggested edits](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits) or "vote to close as duplicate" in the [Close Votes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/review/close) (*synonyms* seems similar to *duplicates*).

#### Plan B

Until such review process is in place, and used to "[let the community vote](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/)" about which tags should yes or no be considered as synonyms, anything about tagging is pretty much depending on what's decided by an authorized user ... which is also why I think it's way more efficient to learn about the [advanced search facilities](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/searching) that are available.

Some examples of such searches (to replace tags that existed before but got removed again):

- [Graphs](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=graph%20is%3Aq) (to separate it from 'Charts', which is not at all the same in Drupal).
- [Paragraphs](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=Paragraphs%20is%3Aq) (about the module 'Paragraphs').
- [403](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=403%20is%3Aq) and [404](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=404%20is%3Aq).
- [Donations](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=donation%20is%3Aq).
- [Training](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=training%20is%3Aq).
- [Spreadsheet](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/search?q=spreadsheet%20is%3Aq).
- ...

Comment: You can continue to bring up issues with any specific re-tagging/synonyms on meta. We don't need another review process for something that happens so rarely. Privileged users have proven themselves to be trustworthy enough to make these decisions without a pre-emptive vote on their opinion. On the odd occasion a mistake is made, we're happy to deal with it after the fact, rather than introduce an arbitrary barrier to getting the site cleaned up.